# c# windows form fails to respond on a click action

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I have a `WindowsForm` project that is running two `BackgroundWorker` objects for testing if data should be collected and the collection of the data. These seem to run ok, but when I add the functionality to look at the data collected, the form freezes upon trying to graph the data available.

When clicking the first button the data is listed in a new form window with list boxes. On this new window I have another button that is for graphing the data if it seems ok.

This is where the whole project freezes. I have tried instead of soft copying the class reference that I pass into the new form, making a new object within the constructor. And as long as the data collection `BackgroundWorker` is not running, it appears to be working ok. When the collection is happening, clicking the plot button freezes the form, the data show button works just fine.

```
private void wellStatusButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     try
     {
        ListDataForm temp = new ListDataForm(tubes[0], 1);
        temp.ShowDialog();
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
     }
  }

private void plotDataButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     try
     {
        GraphForm plotData = new GraphForm(at);
        plotData.ShowDialog();
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
     }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it is running on a background thread and not the UI thread. Try debugging it...

Comment: We'll need to see the implementation of the problem code at a minimum.  Your sample code tells us nothing beyond the fact that you are creating a couple of objects.

Comment: To test what thread is what, set the thread.Name property when creating the threads and on your main thread on the app start to be sure what thread is doing what when debugging.

Comment: With the limited info provided here are some tips to help track down the problem:

Tip 1: Start the application in debug mode and when you detect the app hanging press Ctrl+Alt+PauseBreak and the debugger will halt. You should see an infinite loop or possibly a Sync Lock issue. Using the debugger hunt down the problem like a dog finding a bone...

Tip 2: Use the Threads window, Debug Menu > Windows > Threads

Tip 3: Confirm the ShowDialog modal windows aren't hiding behind the main form? making it seem frozen?

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to get much information from your question, but one thing that might be useful to you is this: When a windows program is doing something else in the background, usually the UI may be frozen. You can try using: Application.DoEvents() periodically, that will allow the UI to appear more responsive.